# How does the infinite loop further down stop earlier code from execution?

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I've come across this weird situation i can't wrap my head around. In the following code, the Program is apparantly enetering the infinite loop, but doesn't execute the code that comes before it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[100];

    if (scanf("%s", buf)==EOF)  return 0;

    printf("This does not get printed");

    while(1) {} //infinite loop
    return 1;
}
```

Somehow, the printf command does not get executed, even after pressing `enter` or using `Ctrl-d`.
However, it seems as if the code would end up in the infinite loop.

Does anyone explain whats going on here? I'm using gcc.

Comment: Add ”\n” to the end and try again.

Comment: It doesn't stop earlier code, it stops the cleanup-on-exit code that flushes the stdout buffer.

Comment: Also, if you compile with optimization the compiler may swap places of statements as long as they don’t affect eachother.

Comment: Damn! With the additional "\n" i really got the line on my screen. Apparently new lines flush the stdout buffer?

Comment: The output is buffered. If you don't want to wait just call `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`, this will cause the standard output to be flushed and the result of the printf will appear immediately.

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch yes, the newline cause the stdout to be flushed

Answer (score 3):

Standard output is line buffered by default. If you write less than a line to the output, some or all of it can be delayed until more output occurs.

Comment: or an input is request.

Comment: Or the line grows bigger than the buffer size, but then only part of the line may be flushed